# Java quiz with multi choices in answers

Tags: java, list, swing, jradiobutton

I'm trying to develop a java quiz, here's the basic idea:
A quiz contains n questions, and a question has 0 to n true answers, I have to link that to a database, so my tables are:

Table `Quiz`:

```sql
id_quiz Integer Primary key, quiz_name Text
```

Table `Question`:

```sql
id_question Integer Primary key, question, id_quiz (foreign key)
```

Table `answer`:

```sql
id_answer Integer primary key, answer TEXT, statut TEXT, id_question (foreign key)
```

So my java classes are:

```
public class Quiz {
    int idQuiz;
    String QuizName;

    public Quiz(int id, String quiz) {
        this.idQuiz = id;
        this.QuizName = quiz;
    }

    // getters ...
}
```

My Question class:

```
public class Question {
    int idQuestion;
    String question;
    int idQuiz;

    public Question(int id, String question){
        this.idQuiz = id;
        this.question = question;
    }

    // getters ...
}
```

and the same for Answer:

```
public class Answer {
    int idAnswer;
    String answer;
    String statut;
    int idQuestion;

    public Answer(int id, String answer, String statut){
        this.idAnswer = id;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.statut = statut;
    }

    // getters ...
}
```

The main `JFrame` contains a `JCombobox` with the list of available quizzes, when the choice is done, a button that send the `idQuiz` to get the List of questions of the chosen quiz.
In my quiz `JFrame`, I made a function that's filling the question `JLabel` with a next button, and the multiple choises of this question with a `JRadioButton` to select.

I have a little problem to get the list of true answers, the user must choose all of true answers, not only one if there is more than one true question.
Has someone an idea about that?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about how to get the list of true answers from your database (= the database select statement) or about what kind of Swing Object you would use for questions with more than one right answer?

Comment: @Mark I mean, how to check if the guy selected the same answers as the answers in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you will need the help of Destructor The Destroyer Of Worlds.

He will attack the answers the user marked as correct one by one until the fate of the user is decided.

First, you need this very important class:

```
public class DestructorTheDestroyerOfWorlds
{
    private static List<Answer> correctAnswers;

    public static boolean destroyAnswers(List<Answer> userAnswers)
    {
        boolean success = true;
        for(Answer userAnswer : userAnswers) 
        {
            success &= destroyAnswer(userAnswer);
        }
        return success;
    }

    private static boolean destroyAnswer(Answer userAnswer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++)
        {
            if (correctAnswers.get(i).idAnswer == userAnswer.idAnswer)
            {
                correctAnswers.remove(i);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isOutOfAmmo()
    {
        return correctAnswers.isEmpty();
    }

    public static void loadUp(List<Answer> answers)
    {
        correctAnswers = answers;
    }
}
```

Now we have to actually get all our information somewhere, so:

```
List<Answer> possibleAnswers = readThoseFromTheDatabase();
List<Answer> correctAnswers = doAFilterOn(possibleAnswers);

List<Answer> userAnswers = new List();
if (checkbox1.isSelected()) userAnswers.add(possibleAnswers.get(0));
if (checkbox2.isSelected()) userAnswers.add(possibleAnswers.get(1));
if (checkbox3.isSelected()) userAnswers.add(possibleAnswers.get(2));
if (checkbox4.isSelected()) userAnswers.add(possibleAnswers.get(3));
```

Then comes the fun part:

```
DestructorTheDestroyerOfWorlds.loadUp(correctAnswers);

boolean successfullyDestroyedAllAnswers = DestructorTheDestroyerOfWorlds.destroyAnswers(userAnswers);

if (successfullyDestroyedAllAnswers && DestructorTheDestroyerOfWorlds.isOutOfAmmo())
{
    System.out.println("Oh fateful user, thy answers were right!");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Oh shameful user, thy answers were wrong!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use checkboxes, not radio buttons.

Radio buttons only allow single choice. Checkbox is the control where you can choose whether to check it or not for every option. Note that this also covers the "no checked answers" option (While it is possible to start with no radio buttons selected, once a user selects *any* radio button, they will be unable to un-select).

Comment: Ok, but how can I compare between the list that I selected and the true answers linked to the question.

Comment: You give answer IDs as ids for the checkboxes and then compare the sent IDs with the correct ones.

Comment: it can't, because if a question has more than one choice and the guy choosed one right answer, it will be ok in this case.

Comment: Why? If you check that all correct answers are present and no other, you cover this scenario as well.

Comment: For example: we have 4 options for a question A, option1 true, option2 false, option3 true, option4 false; if he selected option1 it's true and the answer is taken as right.